# Time deterministic execution of Runnable

Tags: java, bytecode, execution-time, deterministic

Given a Runnable object e.g.

```
public class Test implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        int x = 2;
        int y = 6;
        // Snip more code
        int w = x - 1;
        int z = x * y;          

    }

}
```

I'd like to be able to execute an exact number of operations e.g.

```
Test t = new Test();
Executor.execute(t, 100); // Arbitrary unit of operations
```

Such that if the first time I do this execution runs up to:

```
int w = x - 1;
```

Any other time I call the method with the same parameters will result in execution up to the same point.

I've had a look around and can't see anything suitable (e.g. ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor won't work as far as I can tell).

Will I have to move to the bytecode level to make this worK?  From what I've read the JIT may cause problems here too.

Comment: what do you mean by operation? You mean a call in java? A bytecode op? An op on the processor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject byte code so that it check the timeout after every operation.  This could make it 100x slower or more, but it would be deterministic.

A more pragmatic apporach would be to check the timeout at inveals of your chosing by adding code to the Runnable.

Comment: I guess similar to the way code coverage tools work.  I'll have to try this out and see what the performance impact is.

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap your operations in command objects like so:

```
public interface Operation {       
   int executeOp(int prevResult);
}
```

The runnable would hold a list of these objects and only call say the first 100 of them.